# Looking for all github projects that use a python pacakges

Tags: python, github, package

I'm looking for a tool, script, site or whatever else that show me a list of github prjects (possibly ordered by popularity) that exploit a python package.
 In my case I want to find all projects that exploit `Unidecode` python pacakge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find them in the right sidebar under `Used by` here:
https://github.com/avian2/unidecode/network/dependents?package_id=UGFja2FnZS01MjY3ODE4OA%3D%3D

Answer (score 1):

GitHub has this functionality built in. Under Insights > Dependency Graph > Dependents you can see all GitHub projects that declare a certain package as a dependency in their `setup.py`. In the case of Unidecode the list can be found [here](https://github.com/avian2/unidecode/network/dependents).